# Migration Tool: Salesforce Metadata for Object Buttons, Links, and Actions?

Tags: custom-button, metadata, migration-tool, ant

Not seeing anything related to these in the [Metadata types documenation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm).

Can anyone give me an example of package.xml to retrive this metadata in salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in the objects metadata with the webLinks tag.

Sure in my Account metadata I have the following link:

```
<webLinks>
        <fullName>Billing</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>link</displayType>
        <encodingKey>UTF-8</encodingKey>
        <hasMenubar>true</hasMenubar>
        <hasScrollbars>true</hasScrollbars>
        <hasToolbar>true</hasToolbar>
        <height>600</height>
        <isResizable>true</isResizable>
        <linkType>url</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Billing</masterLabel>
        <openType>newWindow</openType>
        <position>none</position>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <showsLocation>true</showsLocation>
        <showsStatus>true</showsStatus>
        <url>http://www.genwatt.com/genwatt/billing.htm?actname={!Account_Name}</url>
    </webLinks>
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? maybe show a quick xml example

Comment: Oh I see, they can't be retrieved and deployed independently of custom objects (like you can do with custom fields).  Basically its all or nothing when migrating custom objects

Comment: No, you can specify the Weblink metadata type separately. It will appear in the objects directory under the appropriate object, but that object's XML won't include other properties, like fields or related lists, unless explicitly retrieved. There's a typo in the documentation. Docs say it's WebLink, but it's actually Weblink.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to reference these in the Ant Migration tool is to create a WebLink metadata type in your package.xml file.  The actual detail of the button/link will be stored within the custom object xml file.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Contact.Send_SMS</members>
        <name>WebLink</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

Will result with the metadata of the Send_SMS button inside of the Contact metadata file in the objects folder:

objects/Contact.object

The button can then be retrieved and deployed as desired.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <webLinks>
        <fullName>Send_SMS</fullName>
        <availability>online</availability>
        <displayType>button</displayType>
        <linkType>javascript</linkType>
        <masterLabel>Send SMS</masterLabel>
        <openType>onClickJavaScript</openType>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <url>code omitted for brevity</url>
    </webLinks>
</CustomObject>
```

Answer (score 0):

This did resolved the issue for me.
Quick action belongs to 'CustomObjectTranslation' metadata.
And here is the package.xml for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>53.0</version>
</Package>
```