# How to deploy only part of object metadata?

Tags: metadata

I am trying to use [Deploy to Salesforce button](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/09/27/the-new-github-deploy-to-salesforce-tool-button/). From what I understand it is capable deploying the whole object, but I only need to to add field set to existing object without overwriting users settings.

Is it possible?

The closest I've found is [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_fieldset.htm) description about fieldSets. I was trying to retrieve existing fieldsets definitions via package.xml and metadata API with no success.

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of pondering, I've found the answer myself, although [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47020/migration-tool-object-buttons-links-and-actions) has helped a bit.

What I've done is *retrieve* metadata using Workbench using this package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Opportunity.updateAll</members>
        <name>FieldSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

To which I've got response/file *Opportunity.object* which looks just like from the metadata description.

When uploading this file to different organisation, Salesforce works out everything automatically: it uploads the field set based on the filename (Opportunity.object) and upload only that part only.

Comment: This is true for all aspects of an SObject. For example, you can retrieve specific list views, fields, field sets, etc, by name just to get the part(s) you're interested in. For example, I'll often build a package.xml that includes just a list of fields I'm interested in deploying.

Comment: I kinda assumed it, but the hardest part was working out 'retrieve' syntax, as wildcard with FieldSet name wouldn't return anything. Turns out you have to specify object and specific field set name to get it.